# how to stop user from setting his PATH

Tags: linux, shell, security, login

I have set restricted user with limited commands to run with .profile and PATH variable but user can set his path using:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
```

and can get access to other commands.

Is there anyway to restrict user from setting his path?

Comment: use a proper solution such as apparmor selinux simple user account without to much right, but please try to use the correct tool to the correct problem. As soon as a user is able to login with interactive shell or gui he can do whatever he wants with his env. hidding path to binary is also the worst way to protect yourself from anything

Comment: You should restrict the path they can read. Restricting PATH is not a good solution: one could explicitly add the full path in front to the commands. `chroot` could also be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, get it working so `bash -r` did not work but I found `rbash` binary installed which is restricted version of bash.

After adding `/bin/rbash` as a shell for restricted user, it can not set path or execute with complete path and thats what I wanted.
Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: Be aware that `rbash` does not disable Ctrl/C while running the user's login scripts, so it's perfectly possible to break out during the login process. This allows the user to run programs in the standard PATH before it's been locked down or changed. Typically other shells are in that PATH and it's then trivial to escape.

Comment: Very nice, @coder007, I'm glad this helped you find what you were looking for!

Comment: @roaima I got to know about that hack to break into rbash login but if login scripts are read and execute only, it should fix this hack ??

Comment: @coder007 unfortunately no.

Comment: Please note that `rbash` is not really a secure environment for interactive sessions, as there are many ways to escape into a non-restricted shell, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{system("/bin/sh");}'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `readonly` Bash built-in to make a variable, well, read only. But this is unlikely to deter someone bent on changing their environment, as they could simply start a new shell without running the RC files and set up their own environment. Also, **this does not in any way hinder someone from running programs not in the `PATH`.** The `PATH` variable is simply a convenience feature, to allow users to write `foo` rather than for example `/usr/bin/foo`. That's it. It's not related to security in any way.

---

The key to securing an environment is to first take a long hard look at what your threat model is - do you expect users to try to read other users' files, to break the installation, to eavesdrop on communications, to send spam, to get root access, or something else? Once you've established this you can start working out which measures will actually achieve this.

Comment: thats irony, I can add user in other group than root but then ssh can not login. It has to have ssh login and I can set up other group for that user

Comment: What do you mean? Users not in the "root" group can't log in via SSH? If so that's a weird setup.

Comment: Initially there is only root user and group but for this restricted user, I can add new group if needed for permission denial for other commands but ssh also has root only group. I have to find way without changing much.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into bash "restricted" mode (started with `bash --restricted` or `bash -r`), which prevents commands such as `cd` and blocks running any executable by the full path, so it only allows executing what is in `$PATH`.

Also, it prevents modifying environment variables such as `PATH`.

You can find an overview of bash "restricted" mode [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html).

Comment: unfortunately, my shell is ash and not full featured bash. so only options are: Usage: ash [-/+OPTIONS] [-/+o OPT]... [-c 'SCRIPT' [ARG0 [ARGS]] / FILE [ARGS]]

Comment: You can always install `bash`... Anyways, you mentioned "restricted user with limited commands" and `bash -r` fits that description... I don't know what else you think might be restricted. As @l0b0 pointed out, $PATH is just a shortcut, they can access other binaries by using their full path anyways... `bash -r` blocks that too.

Comment: I installed bash and set bash -r shell but problem is I can not ssh login with it  but if I just use bash then I can login. At this point user still in same group as root but in same situation ash can login.